# How to print a phrase n times?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

this may seem like a question that's been asked before, and it is, but there are some tweaks I need help with.

I am writing a program that will print a phrase n times both in upper and lower case **one after another**. My code so far is:

```
expression = str("my name is TONY")
n = int(5)
for i in range(n):
        print(expression.lower())
        print(expression.upper())
```

Lets say the expression is "My name is Tony" and we want it printed 5 times, I am getting the following input:

```
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
```

However, I want the following output, where the phrase is expression is printed **5 times in total, not 10 times like above.**

```
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo operator `%`:

```
expression = "my name is TONY"
n = 5

for i in range(n):
    if i % 2:
        print(expression.upper())
    else:
        print(expression.lower())
```

Prints:

```
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
MY NAME IS TONY
my name is tony
```

Answer (score 0):

I see them repeated 3 times:

```
expression = "my name is TONY"
n = 3

for i in range(n):
    print(expression.lower())
    if not i == 2:
        print(expression.upper())
```